# Minimum distance between a line and a circle in 3D: bracketing triplet?

Tags: geometry, optimization, circles, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

Let $L(t) = B + tM$ be the parametrization of a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let a circle in $\mathbb{R}^3$ be given by a center $C$, a radius $R > 0$, and a unit normal vector $N$ to the plane $\{X \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid N \cdot (X - C) = 0\}$ containing the circle.

What is the minimum distance between the line and the circle?

In the article [*Fast and Accurate Circle-Circle and Circle-Line 3D Distance Computation*](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10867651.2002.10487552) by D. Vranek (2002) it is proposed to substitute $P = L(t)$ into the (explicitly computable) function $d^2(P)$ which gives the squared distance between a point $P$ and the circle, and to numerically minimize this function $$f(t) = d^2(P(t)) = a_6 t^2 + a_5 t + a_4 + a_3\sqrt{a_2 t^2 + a_1 t + a_0},$$ where $$a_6 = M \cdot M,\quad a_5 = 2 D \cdot M,\quad a_4 = D \cdot D + R^2,\quad a_3 = -2R,\quad a_2 = E \cdot E,\quad a_1 = 2E \cdot F,\quad a_0 = F \cdot F,$$ and where $$D = B - C,\quad E = M - (N \cdot M) N,\quad F = D - (N \cdot D) N.$$

In order to start the numerical minimization, is there a clever way to choose a **bracketing triplet** $a,b,c$ such that $b$ is between $a$ and $c$ (so $a < b < c$ or $c < b < a$) and $f(b) < f(a)$ and $f(b) < f(c)$? The article does provide such a choice for the circle-circle case (making use of the periodicity of the function to minimize there), but not in this circle-line case. The source code accompanying the original article (which would probably answer my question) is no longer online, and I haven't managed to contact the author.

*Edit:* At least I could find a bracketing triplet by applying the `mnbrak` function from *Numerical Recipes in C* (Press et al, 1992) to the interval $[(C-B)\cdot M - R, (C-B)\cdot M + R]$. Is there a better way?

*Edit 2:* The minimum could happen to be exactly at $(C-B) \cdot M \pm R$, so the search interval above should be widened.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that it’s possible to get an exact/algebraic solution here, just much less efficient? Here’s a sketch. Project the circle onto two planes—one formed by the line and the center, one perpendicular to that; see the resulting pair of ellipses (or lines &/ points, in edge cases); get the ellipse coefficients (the costly bit); the atan of their quotient gives the angles where the tangent is parallel to the line, which give the projected minima (and maxima); lastly, orthogonal projection, as a special case of parallax, gives the 3D minimum.